# Open Rewrite :Refactoring with declarative YAML recipes

Tags: openrewrite

I have been following the instructions [Refactoring with declarative YAML recipes](https://docs.openrewrite.org/running-recipes/popular-recipe-guides/authoring-declarative-yaml-recipes).
In my case project "A" is a multi-module maven build. I added a module "functional" that has an Example.yml under src/main/resources/META-INF/rewrite. I see Example.yml in the jar file.

My project "B" is a normal maven build (not multi module). It has the rewrite plugin in the pom and with an active recipe which is defined in "A"s Example.yml.

When I run it get the error:

```
    at org.openrewrite.config.Environment.activateRecipes (Environment.java:123)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteMojo.listResults (AbstractRewriteMojo.java:240)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteRunMojo.execute (AbstractRewriteRunMojo.java:54)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
```

When I run: rewrite:discover it does not list my recipe.

In a multiple module maven build where should the yml be located?
Any suggestions for debugging this? If I run rewrite:discover

Here is the rewrite plugin I am using in project B

```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.openrewrite.maven</groupId>
       <artifactId>rewrite-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>4.44.0</version>
       <configuration>
           <activeRecipes>
               <recipe>xxxxx.functional.Example</recipe>
           </activeRecipes>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
```

Comment: It looks like you might need to declare a dependency on module "functional" in the rewrite-maven-plugin configuration block. Can you share the snippet of your pom.xml where you configure rewrite-maven-plugin such that we can confirm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Tim it looks like the problem is that your plugin configuration doesn't declare a dependency on the `functional` artifact containing your recipes. Your plugin should look something like this:

```xml
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.openrewrite.maven</groupId>
       <artifactId>rewrite-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>4.44.0</version>
       <configuration>
           <activeRecipes>
               <recipe>xxxxx.functional.Example</recipe>
           </activeRecipes>
       </configuration>
       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.yourorg.recipes</groupId>
               <artifactId>functional</artifactId>
               <version>1.1.0</version>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>
   </plugin>
```

Please refer to the [documentation](https://docs.openrewrite.org/reference/rewrite-maven-plugin) for more details.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks a lot. I will investigate when I come up for air.